# How to add validation in firebase firestore to prevent adding duplicate doc id

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, react-hooks

I am manually inserting document ID in firestore i.e document of cars

```
  //Example Doc
    cars:{
    chasisNumber :{
      chasisNumber:123dfs,
      carName: BMW 
     }
    }
  //Example Doc
```

In this code if i accidentally add the same **chasis number** again then it overrides the existing values which are store against the existing **chasis number**

```
import db from "./firebase";

function ShowCars() {
const [chasis, setChasis] = useState("");
const [name, setName] = useState("");


const addCar =(e)=>{
e.preventDefault();
db.collection("cars").doc(chasis).set({
 chasisNumber:chasis, 
  carName:name
 });

}
  return (
    <div>
      <form>
        <input placeholder="chasis No" type="text" onChange={(e)=>{setChasis(e.target.value)} value={chasis}/>
        <input placeholder="Car Name" type="text" onChange={(e)=>{setName(e.target.value)} value={name}/>
        <button type="submit" onClick={addCar}>Add</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  )
}

export default ShowCars;
```

i want to avoid passing same doc and in result it should put some msg as alert on the screen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to check if the document already exists, you can do:

```
let docRef = db.collection("cars").doc(chasis)
docRef.get().then((doc) => {
  if (!doc.exists) {
    docRef.set({
      chasisNumber:chasis, 
      carName:name
    });
  }
});
```

---

If you want to prevent the document from being overwritten, you can do in the server-side security rules of your database. For example, this allows creating but not updating the data:

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /cars/{car} {
      allow create: if true;
      allow update: if false;

      allow read: if true;
    }
  }
}
```

For more on this, see the Firebase documentation on [writing security rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/get-started).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to prevent duplication of **chassis number** then follow following steps:-

1. Check your Db (Firestore) by **chassis number** key.

   Please check the code for your easiness.

> import firebase from './../firebase';
> //you can name firebase as DB as you did eailer.

> firebase.firestore().collection('cars').where('chasisNumber','==','yourChasisNumber').onSnapshot((snapshot)
> => {let cars = snapshot.docs.map((doc) => ({
> id: doc.id,
> ...doc.data()
> }));
> return cars;});

2. If it returns some data, break the control in function by using the **return** keyword.
3. Otherwise push your data.

This is the simpler solution that you can try.